# How do i delete some specific rows, using Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete the comments given by the username "vivek" so how do i delete it, using Firebase Realtime database.

here is the screenshot of my database

[image]

Comment: Please refer to this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries

Comment: You can delete data by calling `DatabaseReference.removeValue()` as explained in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#delete_data. If you're having trouble making this work for you case, please update your question with the [minimal complete code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the link please, as creating an MCVE is the best way to get help with code-related questions.

Comment: Please add the code that you have used so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace the database ref to your own**. But how you structure your comment is bad!

```
  private void removeComment() {

    try {

        DatabaseReference remove = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child
                ("Comments").child("user_id").child("my_comment_id");

        remove.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

              Toast.makeText(this, "Comment deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Check your connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to remove vivek, hope this helps:

```
DatabaseReference commentsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("comments");
    commentsRef.child(/* id of the comment */).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String id = snap.getKey();
                String username = snap.child("username").getValue(String.class);

                if (username.equals("vivek")) {
                    DatabaseReference removeRef = dataSnapshot.getRef();
                    removeRef.child(id).removeValue();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```